# Python : Accessing Column Values in multi dimension array

Tags: python, arrays

Example:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

By doing something like `a[:][0]`, I expect it to give me 1st elements in each row `[1,4,7]`

However, I get `[1,2,3]`. I can always make a function to do it.

```
def column(array,index):
    result = []
    for row in array:
        result.append(row[index])
    return result
```

But I was wondering: is there a smarter way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip()`:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> zip(*a)
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
>>> zip(*a)[0]
(1, 4, 7)
```

But note that zip builds tuples, which may require you to convert back to lists depending on your application.

Comment: Note that you are creating N arrays here, unlike the list comprehension. And not everyone will know what zip() does, but it is a lot smaller :).

Comment: More specifically, `zip` builds a list of tuples (as opposed to a tuple of tuples), or an iterator of tuples on Python 3.

Comment: @Russell Borogove: I would strongly advise against such a solution: what you want to do (extract the first element) is obfuscated by the `zip()`, which implies for most Python programmers that the program really needs to keep all the original data, but in a different structure; this is actually a waste of memory and execution time.  Furthermore, this does not work in Python 3, because the result of `zip()` is a generator, in Python 3, so you would need `list(zip(*a))[0]`.  The list comprehension approach is both extremely explicit and standard.

Comment: @JamesAntill, @EOL - you're right about the performance aspect, but something about the phrasing of the question smelled to me like the broader use of `zip()` for transposition might be handy.

Answer (score 3):

The de facto standard way of manipulating arrays in such a way is to use the dedicated [NumPy](http://numpy.org/) package.

Things work the way you want, with NumPy:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> a[:,0]
array([1, 4, 7])
```

In fact, the purpose of NumPy is to provide powerful array manipulations.

Comment: Yes I am aware of numpy but I wanted to avoid using addition library. Good to know thou.

Answer (score 3):

`a[:][0]` doesn't work because `a[:]` [gives a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation/509295#509295) of `a`.  `[0]` then gets the first value from that copy, which is `[1,2,3]`

Instead use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
col = [row[0] for row in a] # => [1,4,7]
```

Comment: Obligatory `map` version: `map(operator.itemgetter(0), a)`.

Comment: @agf: That's why I love Python.  There's always more than one way to do it. ;)

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski: … then you might like Perl better. :)  From the Zen of Python (`import this`): "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a one line for loop, but it is the same as what you already do:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
result = [item[0] for item in a]
```

Comment: It's called a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of list comprehension will do the job:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
col = [c[0] for c in a]
```

No idea of speed implications.

Comment: This is actually quite fast, as far as Python goes.  The usual faster alternative is to use NumPy.